# What kind of website news posting methods are there?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system, feed

I have a custom made website and right now each time I want to put some news on the front page of my site I have to edit the HTML and then re-upload via ftp.
I'm trying to find a simple feature/program that will allow me to post news to my site without manually having to edit the html and possibly allowing it to have comments.

I've tried wordpress but that seems to have too many features. For example it makes me pick a template, which I don't need because I have a custom website. And it has categories, archives, etc. I don't need all of that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress is quite lightweight imo, but if you think it's too big, you might want to use one of these: http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/self-publishing/10-ultra-lightweight-cmses-for-simple-projects/

Comment: I agree. wordpress is very easy to use however I'm not sure if it's built to use for a custom website

Answer (score 0):

Develope your own. Shouldn't take more than a couple of hours.